# Parse specific output into variables Java

Tags: java, parsing

I am trying to find the best way how to parse specific output from jsch when connecting and executing commands on a c7000 HP enclosure.

What I have done so far is written a program that connects to a hp enclosure, executes a command, retrieves the output of the command and converts it from a stream to a String.

I end up with this String

```
Server Blade #1 Information:
    Type: Server Blade
    Manufacturer: HP
    Product Name: ProLiant BL280c G6
    Part Number: 507865-B21     
    System Board Spare Part Number: 531337-001
    Serial Number: XZ73616G9Z      
    UUID: 38926035-5636-5D43-3330-359274423959
    Server Name: SERVERONE
    Asset Tag: [Unknown]
    ROM Version: I25 02/01/2013

    CPU 1: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5520 @ 2.27GHz (4 cores)
    CPU 2: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5520 @ 2.27GHz (4 cores)
    Memory: 49152 MB
```

Now I need to extract some information from this string and put it in a variable/variables. I have tried with regex but don't seem to hack it. What I need is to end up with for example, product name "Proliant BL280c G6" in a string variable that I later can use, same goes with serial number or any other info in there. What I do not need is the preceding text as Type: or Part Number:. I only need to extract what comes after that.

I am pretty new with Java, learning lots every day, can anyone here point me in the right direction of the best way of solving this?

**EDIT**: Thank you very much all for quick responses. I got a few ideas now on how to solve the problem. The biggest help goes to showing me how to use regex expressions correctly. What i missed there was the possibility of excluding string pieces not needed ex. (?<=Product\sName:).

Answer (score 2):

```
String delims = "\n";   //this is the identifier of a line change in java
String[] lines = result.split(delims);  

for (int i=0;i<lines.length;i++)  
{  
        System.out.println(lines[i]);  
}
```

This code will save (and print) the lines in that String (assuming that what you posted is saved as a java String).

You have several ways to do this thou. Sure they will be more reasonable methods to make this (regex, parsers,...), but you can do this to check if a String contains a Substring:

```
 str1.toLowerCase().contains(str2.toLowerCase())
```

So, for example, if you want to know if a line of `lines[i]` contains the word *Product Name*, just make this:

```
 subS = "Product Name";
 if (lines[x].toLowerCase().contains(subS.toLowerCase())); 
 //x being a number between 0 and the total of lines
```

As stated, this is a very rustical method, but it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Asier's method of splitting the lines by the newline character (`'\n'`) and then to get the value of each one you can do `line.substring(line.indexOf(":")+1, line.length())`. You can also get the name of the parameter with `line.substring(0, line.indexOf(":"))`.

You could make a `HashMap` and access them by key:

```
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>(); //or new HashMap<>() if you are on Java 7
String str = "your server stuff goes here";
String[] lines = str.split("\n");
for(int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++)
{
  String curline = lines[i];
  int index = curline.indexOf(":");
  map.put(curline.substring(0, index).trim(), curline.substring(index+1, curline.length()).trim());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, that your response is in source.txt, we read the file

```
File file = new File("source.txt");
BufferedReader fileReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
```

Reading line by line we match it against regexp with lookup behind:

```
String line;
String LOOKUP_BEHIND = "(?<=[a-zA-Z0-9 ]:)";
while((line = fileReader.readLine())!= null){
    Matcher matcher1 = Pattern.compile(LOOKUP_BEHIND + ".+").matcher(line);
    if (matcher1.find()){
        System.out.println(matcher1.group(0));
    }
}
```